# How to declare a global array in Nodejs mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I would like to declare an array to store data which comes from database. i can see the result on console successuly.Result is holding db data.I want to assign result to an array but it becomes empty when i did that. What's the right way ?

```
describe("Test", function () {

    it("Should Update Particular Post Only", (done) => {

        global.postsFromDb = [];//should be filled with db data. 
         chai.request(server)
            .get("/posts")
            .end((err, result) => {
                global.postsFromDb = result.body.slice(); // Doesn't fill global array 
                done();
            })

        console.log( global.postsFromDb);


        var updatedPost = {
            "_id": global.postsFromDb[1]._id,
            "title": "Updated From Test"
        }

        chai.request(server)
            .patch("/posts" + updatedPost)
            .send(updatedPost)
            .end((err, result) => {
                result.should.have.status(200)
                console.log("Updated Particlar Todo Post using / Object ::::", result.body)
                done();
            })
        done();

    })        
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "console.log" line is executed *before* the actual web request is issued, so it logs the empty value that you initialize in

```
global.postsFromDb = [];//should be filled with db data.
```

Please read about the nuances of async Javascript [here](https://dev.to/steelvoltage/if-javascript-is-single-threaded-how-is-it-asynchronous-56gd).

Comment: How did you understand console.log before web request ?

Comment: @Trinity the assignment to global.postsFromDb is done within the "end" method of the request, which will be executed always *after* the _console.log_. At the next run or next test executing, the global.postsFromDb variable will be set accordingly - presuming that it leaves enough time for the http request to complete. But the first time, it will be logged empty I think.

Comment: @Trinity please select the answer as final if it helped.